# mat-select not retaining selected value

Tags: angular, angular-material

select and populating options on select otion calling (selectionChange) and passing event where the event.value is used to have service call where i will get respective json to bind below,
All this is working, once i refresh the page the selected value is not highligted in dropdown.
Below is my code:

```
<mat-select [disableOptionCentering]="true" panelClass="select-box-radio"  (selectionChange)="headerSelection($event)">
                    <mat-option class="select-box-radio-item" *ngFor="let h of firmService.headersData" [value]="h">
                      {{h.headername}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>

headerSelection(event) {

    this.apiService.getFinancialDocumentDetailsFromJSON(event.value.JsonFilePath).subscribe(response => {
        let data = [];
        data.push(response);
        this.coverHeader = data[0].headerSrc;
      }, error => {

        console.log(error);
      })

  }
```

and below this binding is done:

```
<div class="tiny-mc-container" *ngIf="!coverHeaderEditor && coverHeader" [innerHtml]="coverHeader | safeHtml"></div>
```

Comment: Where is the markup that you've placed at the bottom residing? Can you create a Sample StackBlitz replicating the issue? You can fork **[this one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issue-with-mat-select?file=src/app/select-value-binding-example.ts)** and apply your changes to replicate the issue that you're facing.

Comment: Refreshing the page causes all of your components to be re-instantiated, and you are not initializing (nor binding) the model of the mat-select.